# Can someone explain this use of a primitive type in generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, primitive, primitive-types

I'm using the following statement in my Java code and I was surprised to see that it actually compiles:

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url.toString(), byte[].class, params);
```

The signature for this method from the docs is:

```
ResponseEntity<T> getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, ?> urlVariables)
```

I was under the impression that you cannot use primitives in generics in Java. If so, how is this working? Is this essentially syntactic sugar for something else that's going on under the hood? My (quite probably wrong) guess is that the compiler converts `byte[]` to `Array` and somehow works with that. I was wondering if someone could explain to me how and why this works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess, it's because arrays are actually objects (referenced types) in Java, they are immediate subtypes of `Object`. So, generics work for them as for any Java reference type.

Comment: In other words, arrays of primitive values are not primitive types

Comment: Ah, cool! Thanks for the explanation - that makes sense. **edit:** If you're going to downvote this answer, at least have the courtesy to explain why.

Answer (score -5):

That's about a "wrapper" for practical purposes. I mean, despite you're using primitive types (int or byte) you create an object (you know, *new* reserved word is to indicate you're instantiating an object).

Answer (score -6):

I'm assuming you're using JDK 5 or greater. If so, it is cos' of Autoboxing kicking in, to convert the primitive byte[] into Byte[] internally.

Comment: I am affraid that is not true.

Comment: Nothing to do with autoboxing.

Comment: That is incorrect, arrays are not primitives (as explained by Victor Sorokin) so no autoboxing occurs.